# migrating existing data to django-cms plugin

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm migrating from some freestanding apps to django-cms and will be writing my own plugins for some of the more specialized ones (album reviews, for example).  I've not found any documentation on how to import a bunch of data into django-cms and have it play nice with the plugin system (my experience with getting 10+ years of blog posts into zinnia ultimately resulted in me telling zinnia to *NOT* use the django-cms plugin system but to act as a standalone app).  There are hooks into cms_cmsplugin, cms_placeholder, cms_page_placeholders, and I can't figure out how to get the existing data in with the appropriate linkages to show on the pages.

If I import the data to the appropriate table (zinnia_entry, for example) it shows up fine in mysql, but the admin pages show the content field to be empty.

Comment: how can you have 10+ years of blog posts into zinnia ? Django is only 6 years old.

Comment: The posts predate django, originally from a zope based blog, migrated to a custom django blog app I wrote, now into zinnia.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend writing a Python script that handles the migration, using the new Python API for django CMS content in 2.2: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/api.py